# Removing horizontal lines from the header and footer of the title page

Tags: formatting, header-footer, titles, page-numbering

I intend to set two blank pages before my thesis title page. However, the workaround I use does good job for the first page, but introduces horizontal lines
in the title page (there were "text text..." is). The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[algoruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}

% for nice tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
% end for nice tables

% for using color names
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
% end for using color names

% for nicer figure captions
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
% end for nicer figure captions


% fancy headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for upper line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for lower line
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
% end fancy headers and footers

% for shaded table cells
\usepackage{colortbl}

% for multirow option in the tables
\usepackage{multirow}



\usepackage[semicolon]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\newenvironment{myfancybox}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{black}}%
  \color{black}\MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

% for theorems, lemmas...
\theoremstyle{plain}            % use "default" font

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{thma}{Theorem}

%\theoremstyle{definition}      % use "definition-style" font for the rest



%\bibliographystyle{plain} %Choose a bibliograhpic style

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\itshape}

% for height of the heading 
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\parskip1ex
\begin{document}
 \begin{titlepage}
\fancyhf{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
 {\large text text text text
          text text text text text text text text
         text text text text text text text text
          text text text text text text text text} 
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to get two initial pages blank, and the title page without the horizontal lines? Note that the horizontal lines are necessary for the rest of the document, but should be absent from the title page.

Comment: Please use the button "Code sample" (which looks like `{}`) for formatting your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\pagestyle{empty}` instead of `\fancyhf{}` to get empty foot and head lines without lines.